Using SQL how do I group by a field then return totals for another fields for each month and the % change each month?
I have a table called Accounts with the fields Name (string), Month (int), Amount (int).
I want to write a query groups by the Name. Then returns columns for each month showing how much the total Amount for that month was. Then calculate the % difference between each month.
I am not doing this in an application so there is no client. After the SQL query the data is written into a Google Sheet. Would it be easier to format the data using an Apps Script.
I wrote this query, but I would eventually like to also add in the year and this would get really long. Is there a cleaner way to do this?
SELECT
    Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS January,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS February,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 3 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS March,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 4 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS April,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 5 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS May
FROM
    your_table_name
GROUP BY
    Name;


If your column named "month" is INT, then your case expression will not work. At any rate, you could look into the PIVOT function. You are asking two questions here. Sample data and desired output would be very helpful.

If google sheets has pivot functionality and your data is not huge, then I would do it in google sheets. Mysql does not have a built-in pivot functionality, so you are stuck with the above method..
